# Reminders missing from macOS Catalina

Tags: catalina, reminders, ios

I've upgraded my devices to iOS 13 and macOS Catalina. When my iPhone prompted me to upgrade reminders, I went ahead with it since all my devices were now new-reminders capable.

Reminders are working on my mobile devices (iPhone and iPad), but on my macOS Catalina device I just get two reminders: "Where are my reminders?" and "The creator of this list has upgraded these reminders." Since I've already upgraded the device to Catalina, I'm not sure what to do to get it syncing again.

The one thing that's odd about my setup is that the iCloud account with the reminders is a secondary account on the device. I don't use reminders with the primary iCloud account on this device.

Comment: Follow up: I've done a couple of fresh installs, and it looks like this is specific to using a secondary iCloud account. If I use this account as the primary on Catalina, my reminders work. If it's a secondary account, then all I see are "Where are my reminders?"

Comment: I'm annoyed. I saw the message about updating my Mac, which is running High Sierra -- I thought it was talking about last week's Security Update. I installed that and then upgraded the reminders on my iPhone, and now I have no reminders on my Mac, which is how I primarily use them.

Comment: Simple solution for me: I unchecked Reminders in my iCloud settings, then re-created the reminders on my Mac. I only had 4 of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be signed into iCloud with the same Apple ID. You also need to upgrade Reminders to the 'new-style' on your Mac.

Apple's note here describes the changes to [Notifications](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210220)

Comment: > You have to be signed into iCloud with the same Apple ID. 

It is the same Apple ID. 

> You also need to upgrade Reminders to the 'new-style' on your Mac.

How? The Apple docs say that I will be prompted when I open the Reminders app, but I am not prompted.

Comment: Same frustration here, just updated my MacBook to Catalina, can't access any shared reminders with no hint as to what to do.